# Manage multiple versions of same app

Tags: android

I have a shop app that I developing multiple versions of it.
The whole code is the same but I want to release app for each shop with it's special URL, API key, icon and app name.

Currently for each shop I make copy of my project and make changes and finally release the app.
I want to know what is the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the concept of product flavours. Read here for more information: [Configure Build Variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors).

With product flavours, you can keep alternate classes and resources for different flavours.

Answer (score 0):

to do that you need to use build variance technique in build.gradle file in your app where you define for example the paid and free version and which features you need in paid for example .I think this
[tutorial](http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2016/06/18/android-free-paid-versions-tutorial/#.WYcQN4iGOUk) will help you

Answer (score -1):

As per android offical document you can use below techniques to support your app on multiple android versions

**Specify Minimum and Target API Levels:-**

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ... >
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
        ...
    </manifest>
```

**Check System Version at Runtime:-**
android provides a unique code for each platform version in the Build constants class. Use these codes within your app to build conditions that ensure the code that depends on higher API levels is executed only when those APIs are available on the system

```
    private void setUpActionBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```